« Près de » sans déterminant
Au début du roman « Le dernier Syrien », on lit cette phrase : « Des commerçants avaient trouvé un enfant dans un puits, près de pyramides en Égypte. » Ce « près de pyramides » me dérange.
Peut-on écrire « près de » sans aucun déterminant après le « de » ? Je ne peux trouver que deux exemples textuels similaires dans le TLFi :

Vx. Dans le temps de. Synon. près de (infra C 3). C'est un soir, près Noël (Corbière, Amours jaunes, 1873, p.193).
Rare. Un à peu près de (+ subst.). Quelque chose qui ressemble à. Ne trouverai-je pas, sur toute la grande terre, un à peu près de paradis pour une petite créature comme moi? (Colette, Cl. s'en va, 1903, p.318).

Pourtant, le sens de chacun de ces « près de » n'est pas le même de celui de cette citation de Souleimane.

Près "de des" pyramides -> près de pyramides.

Il y a des dizaines de questions similaires. https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22de+des%22

C'est correct de mon point de vue.
Ce "de" permet de rester vague sur l'endroit où se trouve ces pyramides et même sur leur nombre. J'utiliserai cette tournure si on me rapporte un évènement avec peu de faits. Il permet de rester vague et donc de ne pas s'avancer en donnant des précisions qui pourraient être inexactes.
Si on utilise "près des pyramides", on se demandera "lesquelles ?". Ce "de" évite cette interrogation.

C'est correct de tous les points de vue. Pourquoi ne pas expliquer que ce "de" signifie "de des" ?

Bienvenue sur fr.SE. Cette réponse gagnerait à faire un sort au titre de la question: l'OP croit que "de" n'est pas le déterminant de pyramides, alors que c'est la contraction de de+des. De même, dans "près des pyramides", "des" est la contraction de de+les.

@jlliagre Je ne comprends pas ton "de des".

@Frank Comme Fabrice apparemment.

@jlliagre Je ne vois pas la nécessité de ce "de des": près de pyramides et près des pyramides sont deux expressions qui ne posent pas de problème, avec une nuance entre les deux. Pour moi, le de ne signifie pas de des.

@Frank Il faut se poser la question : Quel est le pluriel de "près d'une pyramide".

@jlliagre Près d'un groupe de pyramides ;-)

@Frank Exactement, ou Près de deux pyramides, Près de quelques pyramides, etc. Il n'y a que des qu'on haplologie :-)
